# Reducing several Points within shapefile to single point

Tags: arcgis-desktop, point

as an Output of a zonal-statistics calculation I get points representing the lowest points in each polygon. (the Polygons represent Dolines)

[image: Points]

How can i reduce the number of Points per Polygon to one?
it doesn't matter which of the Points as they all represent the same value.
In the Attribute-table of the Point feature class the ID of the Polygons is already added.

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: ArcMap 10.4 (ArcInfo-License)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use tool [Delete Identical](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-identical.htm):

> Deletes records in a feature class or table which have identical
>   values in a list of fields. If the field Shape is selected, feature
>   geometries are compared.

With Polygon ID field as input field